# Google Sheets: Custom Functions only work with published Editor Add-ons?

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I've been trying to get custom functions working in a Sheets Add-on. However, no matter what I do they won't show up.

Other threads suggest that an add-on must be "published" in order for these functions to show up, but as a public add-on I can't publish until everything is working. (Apparently, it's also not possible to switch this extension to a 'private' one)

So I'm left without a clear approach, unless I'm doing something else that is preventing the custom function from showing. Any suggestions on how to get this fixed?

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message?

Comment: No, everything is working fine aside from no functions available when using the spreadsheet. The App Script is successfully added to the sheet in test mode.

Comment: For this is to work, either you include or create the AppsScript function you've built in every spreadsheet or publishing your add-on as private so you won't undergo the verification process.